# What is AWT-Windows thread?

Tags: java, awt

When I am working with AWT, after calling the `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()`, I have printed the current running threads in my program. I would like to know what is that **AWT-Windows** thread that is running in the background. What does it do and why does it have **6** priority.

Also, the line

```
Thread[AWT-Windows,6,main]
```

does the `main` mean that the thread is started in the main thread?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AWT` is the Java Abstract Window Toolkit. The AWT thread should be handling all AWT events, rendering, etc...

The `6` priority is just one above normal priority to make this scheduler bias slightly towards it.

`main` is the group of the thread.

**EDIT**

The `AWT-Windows` thread specifically handles polling events from the native Windows C++ API for GUIs. The specific native method that handles the events is [`sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java#WToolkit.eventLoop%28%29).

Comment: Then what is the difference between event dispatch thread and this thread?

Comment: No they are not same. You can see AWT-EventQueue thread, a thread that is started when a frame is made visible. This thread handles the AWT events.

Comment: windows events in the sense?

Comment: As in UI/Input events.

Comment: Could you elaborate it?

Comment: At a low level, programs that create frames in Windows must have a loop that handles Windows GUI API events. The AWT-Windows thread is basically a native interface to the loop that polls the Windows API event loop for events.

Comment: That means, for example, when a button is clicked as an AWT button uses the native code, the events are sent to that native code and then the AWT-Windows thread interacts with that native code to know what type of event has occured?

Comment: So an event is first known by the os before it is detected by the program?

Comment: the loop would register a mouse down/mouse up event in the sense, does the OS know that the user pressed on a button or it just knows that the user has pressed at some point?

Comment: But when a program is executed, every component is treated as a standard windows object? I am talking only for AWT here.

Comment: But we usually say that AWT components uses the native code i.e. the code for GUI components that comes with the operating system?

Comment: Then why would we say that AWT is heavy weight and Swing is lightweight? Swing components are coded from the scratch. Also there were classes written in the AWT in sun.awt.windows package. What are these then? Thanks.

Comment: I should delete everything else I have said here. I confused AWT and Swing. Since AWT is heavyweight then the event loop would actually be recieving events corresponding to real native UI components. The `sun.awt.windows` package would be Windows specific code that interfaces with the Windows API. If you were on a different platform, there would be no `sun.awt.windows`.

Comment: That's ok. But the final words are that the AWT-Windows thread interacts with the Windows operating system to know what event has occured and on which component it has occured and then pass it to the event dispatch thread? Am i right? Thanks.

Comment: So, is it right that the Windows os knows that on which component that the user has clicked or just the point?

Comment: Because the OS knows that the component is there and that MFC does tell the application about the target of the event, it logically follows that the OS does know that the user used a certain component.

Comment: I think it is just in the case of AWT because only AWT uses native code, but in the swing case that might be different because swing components are built from the scratch? Am i right?

Comment: Yes. The OS would only know that the event was meant for a certain window because Swing does not tell the OS anything about the components drawn within the window because Swing handles most of it itself.

Comment: In which class was the code written for interaction with the Windows native API?

Comment: I personally do not know. You may be able to figure it out by looking at the trace for the `AWT-Windows` thread.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I do not use IDE, i just use Sublime Text to write programs. I use IDE only for developing apps.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you. I got it. It is sun.awt.windows.WToolkit. But i am seeing for more information.

Comment: Yes! There is a method called `eventLoop()` in it. It is the method in which all this takes place (as from the output). THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!

Comment: Does this thread sleep whenever there is no event and wake up when an event occurs OR just use polling technique which loops to check if there are event(s) occurred?